# Dependant ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a following data structure coming from REST:

> scope.taglist =
>
> [ { name: "mylist", tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", ...]}, { name:
>   "mylist2", tags: ["tag2.1", "tag2.2", "tag2.3", ...]} ]

In order to present the names of the objects I have the following html:

```
<div>
<select ng-model="tagNameSelection">
<option ng-repeat="tagObj in taglist" value="{{tagObj}}">{{tagObj.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="tagdetails">
<!-- present the list of tags from tagNameSelection -->
</div>
```

> Now I am a little bit of a loss on how to present the tags list of
>   individual object.  I am able to present the array in raw  format (by
>   sticking {{tagNameSelection}} inside the tagdetails div) but when I
>   try to iterate through those with ng-repeat angular gives a error
>   message.

Oddly enough when I hard-code one of the tag lists to the scope in controller the ng-repeat works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you interesting something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="fessCntrl">
    <div>
        <select ng-model="tagNameSelection"            
         ng-options="tagObj as tagObj.name for tagObj in taglist"              
         ng-change="change(tagNameSelection)"></select>
    </div>

    <pre>{{tagNameSelection.tags|json}}</pre>

    <div class="tagdetails"> 
        <ul ng-repeat="tag in tagNameSelection.tags">
            <li>{{tag}}</li>
        </ul>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope) {



    $scope.change = function (value) {
    };

    $scope.taglist = [{
        name: "mylist",
        tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
    }, {
        name: "mylist2",
        tags: ["tag2.1", "tag2.2", "tag2.3"]
    }]

});

fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

See <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/583/)</kbd>